# How to load a video from a database table (binary data) into a video element in aspx via C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, video

So I have currently saved a video (.webm) in a database as binary data, and I am having trouble figuring out how exactly I am supposed to use this binary data to convert it back into a viewable media source.  My data table looks like:

```
Id | Name       | Data
1  | Training 1 | NULL
2  | Training 2 | NULL
3  | Training 3 | 0x1A45DFA...
```

And I want to be able to put that data from the third row into a video element in aspx, specifically this one:

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls="controls" runat="server">
    Your browser does not support.
</video>
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a situation when storing textual paths to physical files would make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Make one endpoint that serves .webm files like `/video-files/3`. No other content (like html), just the converted binary data from your database. You'll probably need to include the correct Content-Type value.

Then alter your `<video>` tag to have that url.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by endpoints and I also am not sure what you mean by converted binary data.

Comment: "Endpoint" is just another term for "a url that your application can act on". For example, `/questions/47396798` (this page) is an "endpoint". And what I mean by "converted" (true, it's not really "converted") is you need to make some way for a client browser to download your file so that the `<video>` element can use it.

Comment: for example I currently have code that looks like this (this is the code where I just have the videos in a local directory and not a database): http://puu.sh/yq6mK/83ed646a5f.png    So how would I make an endpoint such that it fits the string "source"?